# Looping jquery function load() using php mysql doesn't work it loop first row only

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to show the posts count depend on topic id using auto load jquery load() after looping the result using php but unfortunately it shows the first row and uses that first row to show another count and change again 
Any Help please!

---

index.php

```
    <?php
    foreach($t_all_rows as $row){
            ?>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                 <a class="font-w600" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                                    function ()
                                    {
            $('#load_posts').load('get_posts.php?t_id=<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
                                    }, 1000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds
                                    </script>

                                   <span id="load_posts"></span>
                </a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <?php } ?>
```

get_posts.php

```
    include('connection.php');
    $db=new DB();
    $conn=$db->db_connect();
    $my_t_id=$_GET['t_id'];
    $post_query = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM post WHERE t_id = "'.$my_t_id.'"');
    $record_count=mysqli_num_rows($post_query);
    //Display count.........
    echo $record_count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is normal, because get only first div by ID, change the span id or add a new class with loop number

Adding $k

```
    foreach($t_all_rows as $k =>  $row){
```

Adding new class

```
<span id="load_posts" class="load_post<?=$k?>"></span>
```

change jquery code:

```
$('.load_post<?=$k?>').load
```

But **importan**, I am suggest to you, to upgrate the mysql query using JOIN and not use jquery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help i finally realize i shoud use class instead of id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                                function ()
                                {
        $('.load_posts<?php echo $index; ?>').load('get_posts.php?t_id=<?php echo $row['t_id']; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
                                }, 1000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds
                                </script>

                               <span class="load_posts<?php echo $index; ?>"></span>
```